# R - write_parquet in loop

Tags: r, loops, csv, parquet

`fwrite` is looping over many `.csv` files in the working directory but when I write a `.parquet` it overwrites each time.

I have tried several approaches, basically I am trying to use file name I to keep the `.csv` file name as shown below without overwriting it.

```
rm(list = ls())
gc()

# Set up environment #
require("data.table")
require("arrow")

# Set directory to data, define files #
setwd("E:/TransferComplete/07/")

files <- list.files(pattern = "csv")

for (i in files){  setwd("E:/TransferComplete/07/")
loopStart <- Sys.time()
  
  bb <- fread(i,header = TRUE,sep = ",", data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                select = c("x","y","z"))
  gc()
  
  
  write_parquet(bb,
  'E:/P/i.parquet')
  
  
  loopEnd <- Sys.time()
  loopTime <- round(as.numeric(loopEnd) - as.numeric(loopStart), 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
write_parquet(bb,
  'E:/P/i.parquet')
```

to this

```
write_parquet(bb,paste0('E:/P/',i,'.parquet'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close in your question. When you're writing the `.parquet`, you need to separate the `i` when writing the file or the loop will keep writing a file called `i.parquet`.

```
write_parquet(bb,paste0('E:/P/',i,'.parquet'))
```